# type alias as class variable of class variable: Name is not defined

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to get to grips with a codebase making heavy use of type hints. The behavior of mypy over the following lines of Python confuses me:

```py
# pkg/types.py
from typing import TypeAlias

class Top:
    alias: TypeAlias = int

class Sub(Top):
    sub = Top
```

```py
# pkg/module.py
from .types import Sub

def func(a: Sub.sub.alias):
    pass
```

```
$ mypy pkg/module.py 
module.py:4: error: Name "Sub.sub.alias" is not defined  [name-defined]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I would expect the name to be defined, since I can import `module.py` fine. Also, annotating with `Sub.alias` instead of `Sub.sub.alias` satisfies mypy.

Comment: Is this construct something you found in the codebase you mentioned? I don't see what purpose it could have, which makes it hard to write an answer that is more helpful than "just use `Sub.alias` if that works".

Comment: the error message doesn't make much sense, but what you are trying to do with type aliases as class attributes seems like it isn't really valid (although, there is sparse specification about this). It doesn't surprise me that it doesn't work.

Comment: although, try renaming `types` to `types_`, note, `types` is a built-in module

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga [Pyright passes this as fine](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAqiApgIIA2SAhgM4BQdAxubTYWAgFx1S9RWVanQiQrU2AXkwoYDZqygBlAK4AjABQEOASm58oNNVClaEDACbFgUYMpSN1VYStUA6Q24HjdPPglYMIMQAbsQCAPrwCMSaHK5etNr6vADEsCQA2qgwALp0QaERUTEu7mpJyanp0RmmeQVh5JEk6qUe8YI0FWnFWTL1IY3N0eq29hWVfGmOwtlJALQAfFAAcmAoxHRAA). Mypy itself [also resolves](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=cf9aa726477290ece44bb0ab08d817d5) `Sub.sub.alias` correctly, but only when used as an argument to `reveal_type()`.

Comment: @InSync yeah, I've been testing it and playing around. One thing to try is to use `sub: TypeAlias = Top`

Comment: @InSync actually, PyRight seems to consider variables Unbound using reveal_type

Comment: testing with pyright in my terminal directly, neither seem to be able to use the `Sub.top.alias` correctly, I am geting Unbound for reveal_type, although mypy seems to "accurately" report the type with reveal_type. They both report an error when I pass a string to the function with a paramter annoated like above.

Comment: So, I'm getting it to work better if I use `sub: TypeAlias = Top` with mypy.

Comment: @Jasmijn yes, this is something I found in the codebase. I myself don't really understand the point of it. @juanpa.arrivillaga @InSync I'm looking at https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases . The fact that it works with `sub: TypeAlias = Top`  is surprising to me, because I would expect `Top.alias` being a type alias the important thing, but not `Sub.sub`. After all when using `Sub.sub.alias` i'm just pointing to the `alias` attribute of class pointed to by `sub`.

Comment: No, `sub: TypeAlias = Top` is also quite important: you refer to it (`Sub.sub`) in *type context*, so it should be something sufficiently static. Without marking it as alias, it's no different from using any other random attribute in a type hint, which is not supportded (and shouldn't be).

Comment: Thanks @STerliakov, maybe my mental model was off, I assumed that `a.b.c` would be resolved like any other python object attribute resolution, the only condition for it to be a valide type hint being that `c` is a valid type hint.